# Excel (if statement, maybe?) Birthday List or Vlookup

Tags: excel, if-statement, vlookup

Hello I am trying to use a simple excel sheet (last name, first name, date of birth, date of hire) for an employee listing to then create a list of birthdays (pro[bably +/- 7 days) - just the last & first name. Secondly the same thing for the hire date (probably +/- 14 days) and the years of service, that calculation I figured out easily.

I was trying to do this with if statements or datedif and am struggling.

maybe this isnt the proper tool, any thoughts, suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Please see sample data screen shot below:

[image]

expected output:
[image]

Maybe this would be better as a vlookup?

Thank you

Comment: Not clear exactly what you are wanting your results to look like in the Excel sheet. Could you please show an example? You can use the Windows snipping tool to capture an image, save it, then edit your question to insert an image if you need to.

Comment: Sorry your question isnt clear. Can you post an example of what you would like your result to be?

Comment: so calculate a range of dates around the current date then use match and index to retrieve the ones that match...

Comment: sorry everyone, my first post... i can be more clear.

Comment: all names , based on their bdays +/- 7 days (of todays date) would be listed, it would be multiple names based on the date and their date of birth, similar for date of hire

Comment: @Zach this is the perfect question for some sample data. Show some inputs with the expected outputs and [edit] your question with a screen shot of your sheet

Answer (score 0):

OK, so here is what I came up with based on my understanding of the question:

```
=IF(OR(DATEDIF(B2,TODAY(),"YD")<=7,DATEDIF(B2,TODAY(),"YD")>=359),A2,"NO")
```

The formula here takes number of days between the birthday and today (ignoring the years) and checks if they're less than or equal to 7 or  more than or equal to 359.

Sample spreadsheet: https://www.dropbox.com/s/kxgi9eeoikems66/Birthday.xlsx?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

Insert two more columns for month of birth and month of hiring. Add the following formula in both consecutively

```
=TEXT(C1,”MMMM”) and =TEXT(D1,”MMMM”)
```

The final sheet will look like this

[image]

After that select all of your data and insert Pivot table and format it like the below

[image]

You will get an auto updatable sheet without any macros and extra work